# how do I find a company's historical growth rate and read it?

Tags: stocks

I went over to Yahoo Finance and looked up the company AMTD to look up its financial growth rate over the past two years and got this - https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMTD/history?period1=1483257600&period2=1571727600&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo

I am a newbie to stocks and not sure exactly where to read in the charts to determine the company has grown X percent over the past two years. How do I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Growth in what?  Sales? Revenues?  Earnings? Share price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to measure size, and therefore growth of a company.  The appropriate measure depends on the question you are trying to answer.

A few measures that roughly give a sense of "size" you may want to compare year over year include:

Revenue: How much does the company sell?

Assets: The total value of the company's assets (equal to debt + equity)

Market capitalization: How much the market values the company's equity

Income: How much profit does the company generate